# Why is this block not global?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (^block)();

block foo() {
  char a = 'a';
  return [^{
    printf("%c\n", a);
  } copy];
}

block bar() {
  const char a = 'a';
  return [^{
    printf("%c\n", a);
  } copy];
}
```

This is what that compiles to for armv7:

```
_foo:
@ BB#0:
        push    {r7, lr}
        mov     r7, sp
        sub     sp, #24
        movw    r3, :lower16:(L__NSConcreteStackBlock$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC0_0+4))
        movt    r3, :upper16:(L__NSConcreteStackBlock$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC0_0+4))
        movw    r1, :lower16:(___foo_block_invoke_0-(LPC0_1+4))
LPC0_0:
        add     r3, pc
        movt    r1, :upper16:(___foo_block_invoke_0-(LPC0_1+4))
        movw    r0, :lower16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC0_2+4))
LPC0_1:
        add     r1, pc
        movt    r0, :upper16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC0_2+4))
        movw    r2, :lower16:(___block_descriptor_tmp-(LPC0_3+4))
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        movt    r2, :upper16:(___block_descriptor_tmp-(LPC0_3+4))
        str     r3, [sp]
        mov.w   r3, #1073741824
LPC0_2:
        add     r0, pc
        str     r3, [sp, #4]
        movs    r3, #0
LPC0_3:
        add     r2, pc
        str     r3, [sp, #8]
        str     r1, [sp, #12]
        ldr     r1, [r0]
        mov     r0, sp
        str     r2, [sp, #16]
        movs    r2, #97
        strb.w  r2, [sp, #20]
        blx     _objc_msgSend
        add     sp, #24
        pop     {r7, pc}

_bar:
@ BB#0:
        movw    r1, :lower16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC2_0+4))
        movt    r1, :upper16:(L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_-(LPC2_0+4))
        movw    r0, :lower16:(___block_literal_global-(LPC2_1+4))
LPC2_0:
        add     r1, pc
        movt    r0, :upper16:(___block_literal_global-(LPC2_1+4))
LPC2_1:
        add     r0, pc
        ldr     r1, [r1]
        b.w     _objc_msgSend
```

What confuses me is the first block is not a global block. It's a stack block and then copied. That doesn't make sense to me. Is it something I'm overlooking in the C-standard for why the compiler can't automatically infer that `a` can actually be considered `const`?

I'm building this `Os`, ARC enabled, and here's my clang version:

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I don't think it can't, I think it's just not smart enough. What happens if you replace the block with something simpler, e.g. `return a + 1;`?

Comment: Might just be a missed optimization opportunity. You should file a bug report.

Comment: @GregParker yeh I would file a big report if I know that it's definitely a missed optimiser opportunity.

Comment: @Sulthan good point. That will certainly return 'b' directly for sure. Missed opportunity it is then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `char a` requires storage, and this means that the block in `foo` requires its own variable `a` which is initialised to the *value* of `foo`'s `a`. The block's variable is stored in it's "environment".

The declaration `const char a` does not *require* storage to be allocated unless the address of `a` is taken (by the C Language Specification). Any use of `a`'s value can be replaced directly by its constant value. This means that `bar` can be compiled without any environment.

So the two blocks are compiled differently.

In theory a compiler, if the language specification doesn't disallow it, might be able examine the declaration and use of a variable, determine that it is not externally visible, determine its value never changes after initial assignment and that its address is never taken, and then replace the variable by a constant value... but that's a lot of analysis for probably a small, if any, payoff.

Comment: Yeh all makes sense - I was just hoping the optimiser would do the optimisation. I know that it doesn't *have* to, but is it just because it hasn't, or is there some reason in standards that mean it *can't*? I guess the former right?

Comment: FWIW the payoff is pretty big here. Look at the difference in the generated code. Also, there's no need for block copies in the global block case. That could be a significant improvement. Whether or not this is a likely case to occur is another matter.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - There is nothing I know of in the C Language Specification which would prevent this optimisation. The issue is whether it is worthwhile, and without looking into the Clang source we cannot say; I can see reasons why it may not have been done in this case (if you take out the block and just `printf` a non-const var the var is elided). But why not submit it as a potential optimisation opportunity to Apple's Bug Reporter? It can't do any harm.

Comment: Already filed yes :-). Just wanted to check on here first in case I was going mad. I too couldn't think of any reason why it can't be optimised. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: can you perhaps edit your answer to indicate that it *could* be optimised, but it's just that the optimiser isn't doing it. I would then accept.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - last para?

Comment: True. I just thought it should be right at the start, otherwise it reads as though the reason they compile differently is *because* it requires storage in the `foo` case.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - but it *does* require the storage unless, an as yet theoretical, optimisation can remove the need... It will be interesting to see if Apple add such an optimisation. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, but the fact it requires storage is not the answer to the question. The answer is "no there is no reason why it can't optimise that". Indeed very interesting to see what Apple say!