# Why does ARC copy this block to the heap?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Consider this simple example

```
int i = 42;
int (^aBlock)() = ^ {
    return i;
};
NSLog(@"Class: %@", [aBlock class]);
```

Without ARC the above code prints

```
Class: __NSStackBlock__
```

whereas with ARC it prints

```
Class: __NSMallocBlock__
```

I placed a symbolic breakpoint on `_Block_copy` and it looks like ARC is inserting a `Block_Copy()` call, causing the block to be moved to the heap

It seems an unnecessary overhead and it defeats the whole purpose of having blocks on the stack in the first place.

Is this a limitation of ARC or is it a design choice?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Why is this block not global?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957319/why-is-this-block-not-global) to me, do you agree? - (I don't find the accepted answer fully satisfying, but perhaps there is no better answer, or it is just a compiler bug.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, but no, not really. That question is about why the block is not compiled as global, whereas I'd like to know why ARC inserts that `Block_Copy()`.

Comment: And note that I purposely ensured that the block is not global by making a reference to the surrounding scope.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert in assembler code, but if I understand the text of that question correctly, a unexpected "block copy" is inserted there as well, moving the global block to the heap. - And if you replace `int i = 42` by `const int i = 42` then you get a global block, which is the same behavior as in then second example of the referenced question.

Comment: A global block is already on the heap, isn't it? Anyway I see your point, but I still believe this is not about the block type being misinterpreted by the compiler. In this case the block type is known (it is indeed a stack-block, which is being copied to the heap). The question is: why does ARC copies a stack-block? Thanks to the comment from Catfish_Man I got an idea of where to look at, I did my homework and I tried to answer below. Let me know what you think

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong terms. In the first example of the referenced question, the block starts as a stack block and is then copied, and the same seems to happen in your code. So I still think that it is a duplicate question. - That does not mean that there is no room for another explanation.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still different. The OP there is not baffled by the copy being inserted as he explicitly calls `copy` in the example. He's wondering why the compiler misinterprets the block type, which in my example is instead out of discussion. In other words, in his case the compiler makes a wrong assumption about the block type and does the right thing given the assumption; in my case the compiler makes the right assumption about the type and it appears to be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. You are asking why the block is copied at all (and your answer explains it, +1). The other question is why the block copy does not create a global block.

Comment: You got my question right (sorry for being unclear, it took me a few attempts to find the right words), but I think the other question is more about why the block that is being copied is not global in the first place (copying a block shouldn't make it global if it wasn't).

Comment: @MartinR: There are 3 kinds of blocks: global blocks, stack blocks, and malloc blocks. A block that does not capture any variables will be a global block. A block that captures variables starts out as a stack block and when copied becomes a malloc block. The storage is analogous to global variables vs. local and malloc'ed variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Block pointers types are considered [retainable object pointers types](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers) by ARC and such types - in absence of explicit ownership qualifier - are implicitly assumed to have a `__strong qualifiers`, as per the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects):

> If an object is declared with retainable object owner type, but without an explicit ownership qualifier, its type is implicitly adjusted to have __strong qualification.

So the above example is equivalent to

```
int i = 42;
__strong int (^aBlock)() = ^ {
    return i;
};
NSLog(@"Class: %@", [aBlock class]);
```

The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics) also states:

> For `__strong` objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old pointee is released.

and [later](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks)

> [...] whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a Block_copy [...]

So yes, ARC introduces a `Block_copy` call whenever assigning a block to a variable, since the variable is implicitly assumed considered to be `__strong`-qualified.

Skipping the assignment will keep the block on the stack. Consider the following example:

```
NSLog(@"Class: %@", [^int{return i;} class]); // => Class: __NSStackBlock__
```

The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks) also tells us that

> The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call.

And indeed it does. As proposed by Catfish_Man, turning the optimizations on (in this case by using the Release build configuration) will strip away the `Block_Copy` call, leaving the block on the stack.